# Custom .Replace method that replaces with HTML?

Tags: c#, html, twitter-bootstrap, asp.net-mvc-4, html-encode

I have a need to replace a simple string with HTML (from twitter Bootstrap's glyphicon elements). I use the standard c# `.Replace()` method as follows:

```
.Replace("chkbox", "<span class=\"glyphicon glyphicon-check\"></span>")
```

but in my browser, it appears as text `<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-check"></span>` instead of rendering it as HTML. When I 'inspect' the element it appears as `&lt;span class="glyphicon glyphicon-check"&gt;&lt;/span&gt;`

I've tried using `Html.Raw()`, `MvcHtmlString.Create()`, `.ToHtmlString()` but none of these work.

I believe the only way will be  to create my own `.Replace(string old, HTMLString new)` method, or something to that effect. Where/How in my mvc application do I code this method?

Comment: is that on the view or in the controller? the .Raw will need to be called on the view best i can remember

Comment: It is in the view yes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default MVC does not output raw HTML but encodes it.

To achieve your requirement you need to explicitly output the raw html.

```
Html.Raw(MyString.Replace("chkbox", "<span class=\"glyphicon glyphicon-check\"></span>"))
```

Comment: @barnacle.m If this is part of a large string, then you will have to output the entire string as raw - Updated the answer.

Comment: That actually solves the problem I was having. Much appreciated.